Customizing references
I am writing my thesis and trying to modify the references to conform with the recommended style by the department. Please feel free to suggest any adjustments and let me know if more information is needed.
---------------The desired format:---------------
Erdal, Marcel. 2007. Group inflexion, morphological ellipsis, affix suspension, clitic sharing. In Fernandez-Vest, M. M. Jocelyne (ed.), Combat pour les langues du monde: Hommage à Claude Hagège, 177–189. Paris: L’Harmattan.
Pérez Hernández, Lorena & Ruiz de Mendoza, Francisco José. 2002. Grounding, semantic motivation, and conceptual interaction in indirect directive speech acts. Journal of Pragmatics 34(3). 259–284.
Johnson, Kyle & Baker, Mark & Roberts, Ian. 1989. Passive arguments raised. Linguistic Inquiry 20. 219–251.
Rissanen, Matti. 1999. Syntax. In Lass, Roger (ed.), Cambridge history of the English language, vol. 3, 187–331. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press
San Roque, Lila. 2019. Evidentiality. Annual review of anthropology 48. 353–370. DOI: 10.1146/annurev-anthro-102218-011243.
---------------Current format is in the screenshot.---------------
---------------Main aimed modifications:---------------

No single quote between article names. (although some other references do not have this)
In + {author name} + (ed.) + comma + article name
When there are more than two authors (or editors), each pair of names is separated by an
ampersand (example 3)
Volume number followed by an issue number in parentheses like 34(3) in the second example
If there is only a volume number, it is displayed as Vol. {number} as in the example 4
Display the DOI in the format DOI: 10.1146/annurev-anthro-102218-011243. (example 5)


---------------The code I use:---------------
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

% Package Inclusion:**

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, sorting=nyt, innamebeforetitle=true]{biblatex}

% Name Formatting:**

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

% Editor and Translator Formatting:**

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

% Pages Punctuation:**

\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\addcomma\addspace}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addperiod\addspace}}

% Title Punctuation:**

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{innametitledelim}{\addspace}
\renewcommand{\intitlepunct}{\space}

% Article Title Formatting:**

\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{title}{#1}

% Bibliography Resource:**

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% Formatting DOI:**

%\renewcomm\&{\doiprefix}{https://doi.org/}

% Language Mapping:**

\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

% Volume Number Formatting:**

\DeclareListFormat[article]{volume}{#1}

% Final Name Delimiter:**

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\final\&comma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}

% Open and Close Parentheses Formatting:**

\renewcommand{\bibopenparen}{\adddot\addspace}
\renewcommand{\bibcloseparen}{\adddot\addspace}

% Number Formatting:**

\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, misc, thesis, unpublished]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Page Field Formatting:**

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}




\begin{document}


\sloppy\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, notkeyword=this, title=References]

---------------Data in the bib file:---------------
@article{Ludewige2017,
 author = {Julia Ludewige},
 journal = {{CLCWeb: Comparative Literature and Culture}},
 title = {{TED Talks as an Emergent Genre}},
 volume = {19},
number = {1},
 year = {2017}
}

@Misc{OpenRefine,
title =    {{OpenRefine}},
howpublished = {\url{https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine}},
year = {2010--2024}
}

@article{LandisKoch1977,
 author = {Landis, J. Richard and Koch, Gary G.},
 journal = {{Biometrics}},
 title = {{The measurement of observer agreement for categorical data}},
 volume = {33},
number = {1},
 year = {1977}
}

@article{Cohen1960,
 author = {Cohen, Jacob},
 journal = {{Educational and Psychological Measurement}},
 title = {{A coefficient of agreement for nominal scales}},
 volume = {20},
number = {1},
 year = {1960},
pages = {37--46}
}

@article{Fleiss1971,
 author = {Fleiss, Joseph L.},
 journal = {{Psychological Bulletin}},
 title = {{Measuring nominal scale agreement among many raters}},
 volume = {76},
number = {5},
 year = {1971},
pages = {378--382}
}


@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
@article{collins2011a,
  author = {Collins, Tom and Laney, Robin and Willis, Alistair and Garthwaite, Paul H.},
  title = {Modeling pattern importance in {C}hopin's mazurkas},
  journal = {Music Perception},
  year = 2011,
  volume = 28,
  number = 4,
  pages = {387--414}
}

@inproceedings{collins2013,
  author = {Collins, Tom and Arzt, Andreas and Flossmann, Sebastian and Widmer, Gerhard},
  title = {{SIARCT-CFP}: improving precision and the discovery of inexact musical patterns in point-set representations},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the International Society for Music Information Retrieval Conference},
  year = 2013,
  editor = {Britto Jr, Alceu S. and Gouyon, Fabien and Dixon, Simon},
  pages = {549--554},
  publisher = {International Society for Music Information Retrieval},
  address = {Curitiba, Brazil},
  note = {Retrieved 13 November, 2013 from \href{https://tomcollinsresearch.net/pdf/collinsEtAlISMIR2013.pdf}{https://tomcollinsresearch.net/pdf/\\
   collinsEtAlISMIR2013.pdf}}
}

@incollection{collins2016,
  author = {Collins, Tom and Arzt, Andreas and Frostel, Harald and Widmer, Gerhard},
  title = {Using geometric symbolic fingerprinting to discover distinctive patterns in polyphonic music corpora},
  booktitle = {Computational Music Analysis},
  year = 2016,
  editor = {Meredith, David},
  pages = {445--474},
  publisher = {Springer},
  address = {Berlin, Germany}
}

@phdthesis{collins2011b,
  author = {Collins, Tom},
  title = {Improved methods for pattern discovery in music, with applications in automated stylistic composition},
  school = {Faculty of Mathematics, Computing and Technology, The Open University},
  year = 2011
}

@book{ross2006,
  author = {Ross, Sheldon},
  title = {A first course in probability},
  year = 2006,
  publisher = {Pearson Education, Inc},
  address = {Upper Saddle River, NJ},
  edition = {7th}
}

@misc{lunn2007a,
  author = {Lunn, Daniel},
  title = {Part {A}: Statistics lecture notes},
  year = 2007,
  note = {Retrieved 15 July, 2010 from \href{http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~dlunn/A5_06/A5_2006.htm}
        {http://\\
        www.stats.ox.ac.uk/$\sim$dlunn/A5\_06/A5\_2006.htm}}
}

@misc{lunn2007b,
  author = {Lunn, Daniel},
  title = {Part {B}: Applied statistics lecture notes},
  year = 2007,
  note = {Retrieved 15 July, 2010 from \href{http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~dlunn/BS1_05/BS1_mt05.htm}{http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/$\sim$dlunn/BS1\_05/BS1\_mt05.htm}}
}

@article{shannon1948,
  author = {Shannon, Claude E.},
  title = {A mathematical theory of communication},
  journal = {Bell System Technical Journal},
  year = 1948,
  volume = 27,
  pages = {379-423, 623-656}
}

@inproceedings{rahman2019centroidb,
  title={Centroid of Age Neighborhoods: A Generalized Approach to Estimate Biological Age},
  author={Rahman, Syed Ashiqur and Adjeroh, Donald},
  booktitle={2019 IEEE EMBS International Conference on Biomedical \& Health Informatics (BHI)},
  pages={1--4},
  year={2019},
  organization={IEEE},
  doi={10.1109/BHI.2019.8834608}
}
@article{bahdanau2014neural,
  title={Neural machine translation by jointly learning to align and translate},
  author={Bahdanau, Dzmitry and Cho, Kyunghyun and Bengio, Yoshua},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1409.0473},
  year={2014},
  doi={10.48550/arXiv.1409.0473}
}
@article{imboden2018cardiorespiratory,
  title={Cardiorespiratory fitness and mortality in healthy men and women},
  author={Imboden, Mary T and Harber, Matthew P and Whaley, Mitchell H and Finch, W Holmes and Bishop, Derron L and Kaminsky, Leonard A},
  journal={Journal of the American College of Cardiology},
  volume={72},
  number={19},
  pages={2283--2292},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Elsevier},
  doi={10.1016/j.jacc.2018.08.2166},
}
@inproceedings{motiian2017unified,
  title={Unified deep supervised domain adaptation and generalization},
  author={Motiian, Saeid and Piccirilli, Marco and Adjeroh, Donald A and Doretto, Gianfranco},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the IEEE International Conference on Computer Vision},
  pages={5715--5725},
  year={2017}
}
@book{american2013acsm,
  title={ACSM's guidelines for exercise testing and prescription},
  author={American College of Sports Medicine and others},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Lippincott Williams \& Wilkins}
}
@book{murphy2012machine,
  title={Machine learning: A probabilistic perspective},
  author={Murphy, Kevin P},
  year={2012},
  publisher={MIT press}
}
@article{ji20123d,
  title={3D convolutional neural networks for human action recognition},
  author={Ji, Shuiwang and Xu, Wei and Yang, Ming and Yu, Kai},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence},
  volume={35},
  number={1},
  pages={221--231},
  year={2012},
  publisher={IEEE},
  doi={10.1109/TPAMI.2012.59}
}
@inproceedings{krizhevsky2012imagenet,
  title={Imagenet classification with deep convolutional neural networks},
  author={Krizhevsky, Alex and Sutskever, Ilya and Hinton, Geoffrey E},
  booktitle={Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems},
  pages={1097--1105},
  year={2012}
}
@article{horvath2018dna,
  title={DNA methylation-based biomarkers and the epigenetic clock theory of ageing},
  author={Horvath, Steve and Raj, Kenneth},
  journal={Nature Reviews Genetics},
  volume={19},
  number={6},
  pages={371},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group},
  doi={10.1038/s41576-018-0004-3}
}
@article{pyrkov2018quantitative,
  title={Quantitative characterization of biological age and frailty based on locomotor activity records},
  author={Pyrkov, Timothy V and Getmantsev, Evgeny and Zhurov, Boris and Avchaciov, Konstantin and Pyatnitskiy, Mikhail and Menshikov, Leonid and Khodova, Kristina and Gudkov, Andrei V and Fedichev, Peter O},
  journal={Aging (Albany NY)},
  volume={10},
  number={10},
  pages={2973},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Impact Journals, LLC},
  doi={10.18632/aging.101603}
}
@inproceedings{wang2018face,
  title={Face aging with identity-preserved conditional generative adversarial networks},
  author={Wang, Zongwei and Tang, Xu and Luo, Weixin and Gao, Shenghua},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition},
  pages={7939--7947},
  year={2018}
}
@article{lecun2015deep,
  title={Deep learning},
  author={LeCun, Yann and Bengio, Yoshua and Hinton, Geoffrey},
  journal={Nature},
  volume={521},
  number={7553},
  pages={436},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group},
  doi={10.1038/nature14539}
}
@article{zhang2018fine,
  title={Fine-Grained Age Estimation in the wild with Attention {LSTM} Networks},
  author={Zhang, Ke and Liu, Na and Yuan, Xingfang and Guo, Xinyao and Gao, Ce and Zhao, Zhenbing},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1805.10445},
  year={2018},
  doi={10.1109/TCSVT.2019.2936410}
}
@article{ravi2016deep,
  title={Deep learning for health informatics},
  author={Rav{\i}, Daniele and Wong, Charence and Deligianni, Fani and Berthelot, Melissa and Andreu-Perez, Javier and Lo, Benny and Yang, Guang-Zhong},
  journal={IEEE {J}ournal of {B}iomedical and {H}ealth {I}nformatics},
  volume={21},
  number={1},
  pages={4--21},
  year={2016},
  publisher={IEEE},
  doi={10.1109/JBHI.2016.2636665}
}

@article{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
  journal = {Civil Service Journal},
  doi     = {10.2214/ajr.12.9928__##},
}


@article{HIGGINS2012194,
title = {Ethos, logos, pathos: Strategies of persuasion in social/environmental reports},
journal = {Accounting Forum},
volume = {36},
number = {3},
pages = {194-208},
year = {2012},
note = {Analyzing the Quality, Meaning and Accountability of Organizational Communication},
issn = {0155-9982},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.accfor.2012.02.003},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0155998212000178},
author = {Colin Higgins and Robyn Walker},
keywords = {Rhetoric, Discourse, Persuasion, Sustainability, Reporting, Critical analysis, New Zealand},
abstract = {We demonstrate how persuasive strategies activate the ‘middle ground’ discourses of responsible and sustainable business constructed in three social/environmental reports. Drawing on insights from impression management and communication studies, and Kenneth Burke's understanding that rhetoric is all pervasive, we focus on Aristotle's rhetorical ‘proofs’: ethos (credibility), logos (reason), and pathos (emotion). We study the social/environmental reports produced by three New Zealand companies during a wider discursive struggle over the ‘proper’ role of business in society. We argue that persuasive strategies facilitate the social effects of ‘middle ground’ discourse by making business-centred understandings of social responsibility and sustainability appear reasonable and business organisations appear trustworthy in their pursuit of sustainable development. This study complements discourse analyses of social/environmental reporting by providing a finer-grained picture of how language use influences how social actors think, feel and act.}
}

@Inbook{Artstein2017,
author="Artstein, Ron",
editor="Ide, Nancy
and Pustejovsky, James",
title="Inter-annotator Agreement",
bookTitle="Handbook of Linguistic Annotation",
year="2017",
publisher="Springer Netherlands",
address="Dordrecht",
pages="297--313",
abstract="This chapter touches upon several issues in the calculation and assessment of inter-annotator agreement. It gives an introduction to the theory behind agreement coefficients and examples of their application to linguistic annotation tasks. Specific examples explore variation in annotator performance due to heterogeneous data, complex labels, item difficulty, and annotator differences, showing how global agreement coefficients may mask these sources of variation, and how detailed agreement studies can give insight into both the annotation process and the nature of the underlying data. The chapter also reviews recent work on using machine learning to exploit the variation among annotators and learn detailed models from which accurate labels can be inferred. I therefore advocate an approach where agreement studies are not used merely as a means to accept or reject a particular annotation scheme, but as a tool for exploring patterns in the data that are being annotated.",
isbn="978-94-024-0881-2",
doi="10.1007/978-94-024-0881-2_11",
url="https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-024-0881-2_11"
}

@inproceedings{zeinert-etal-2021-annotating,
    title = "Annotating Online Misogyny",
    author = "Zeinert, Philine  and
      Inie, Nanna  and
      Derczynski, Leon",
    editor = "Zong, Chengqing  and
      Xia, Fei  and
      Li, Wenjie  and
      Navigli, Roberto",
    booktitle = "Proceedings of the 59th Annual Meeting of the Association for Computational Linguistics and the 11th International Joint Conference on Natural Language Processing (Volume 1: Long Papers)",
    month = aug,
    year = "2021",
    address = "Online",
    publisher = "Association for Computational Linguistics",
    url = "https://aclanthology.org/2021.acl-long.247",
    doi = "10.18653/v1/2021.acl-long.247",
    pages = "3181--3197",
    abstract = "Online misogyny, a category of online abusive language, has serious and harmful social consequences. Automatic detection of misogynistic language online, while imperative, poses complicated challenges to both data gathering, data annotation, and bias mitigation, as this type of data is linguistically complex and diverse. This paper makes three contributions in this area: Firstly, we describe the detailed design of our iterative annotation process and codebook. Secondly, we present a comprehensive taxonomy of labels for annotating misogyny in natural written language, and finally, we introduce a high-quality dataset of annotated posts sampled from social media posts.",
}

Thank you for your help!

Welcome! Please edit your question to (1) remove code we don't need to reproduce the issue and (2) add code we do need in order to compile the example and reproduce the issue. It may be easier to use biblatex-examples.bib if you can produce the issue that way, since everyone has that already. It would be better not to put entire titles into braces as doing so makes the data less flexible an can interfere with formatting. Use title-style capitalisation in the .bib and set options to use sentence-style if required. Use doi,  eprint, url, urldate etc. rather than ad hoc formatting.

Hi, cfr! Thanks for your correction suggestions. Let me know if it works. The deadline is approaching, so I desperately need to wrap this up.

As I say, you will get some of what you want if you use the intended fields for things like doi and don't put them as URLs. You don't need the full url for those - just the doi proper. Similarly, use the url/urldate fields and maybe try @online rather than @misc for online resources.

I wrote your code for you and organised it neatly. Just before the command \begin{document}, you'll find the five answers to your questions in order.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addperiod\addspace}{\addcomma\addspace}}
\renewcommand{\intitlepunct}{\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}


% First
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,inreference,unpublished]{title}%
        {\mkbibquote{#1}}

% Second
\newbibmacro*{bbx:editorfirst}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\ifuseeditor}
                and
                not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}}
        {\printnames{editor}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}
            \bibstring[\mkbibparens]{editor}%
            \clearname{editor}\newunit}
        {}}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \bibstring{in}%
    \setunit{\intitlepunct}%
    \usebibmacro{bbx:editorfirst}}

% Third
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addspace\&\addspace}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\addspace}

% Fourth
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \iffieldundef{number}%
        {\iffieldundef{volume}%
            {}%
            {\bibstring{volume}%
            \setunit{\addspace}%
            \printfield{volume}}}%
        {\printfield{volume}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
        \printfield{number}}}%
    \setunit{\bibeidpunct}%
    \printfield{eid}}

% Fifth
% The DOI field is already as you are committing
% In case: \DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\bibstring{doi}\addcolon\addspace\href{http://doi.org/\printfield{doi}}{\printfield{doi}}}

% .bib file omitted

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \cite{Ludewige2017,OpenRefine,LandisKoch1977,Cohen1960,Fleiss1971,greenwade93,collins2011a,collins2013,collins2016,collins2011b,ross2006,lunn2007a,lunn2007b,shannon1948,rahman2019centroidb,bahdanau2014neural,imboden2018cardiorespiratory,motiian2017unified,american2013acsm,murphy2012machine,ji20123d,krizhevsky2012imagenet,horvath2018dna,pyrkov2018quantitative,wang2018face,lecun2015deep,zhang2018fine,ravi2016deep,appleby,HIGGINS2012194,Artstein2017,zeinert-etal-2021-annotating}
\end{itemize}


\printbibliography
\end{document}

I organised your code, but not your bibliography file yet. However, your bibliography file is a serious mess!
Please, note that I corrected the OpenRefine entry: the biblatex package requires time interval to be formatted like this: date={YYYY-MM-DD/ZZZZ-NN-EE}, where the month and day are optional and the slash is simply a separator in the code.
So, it's up to you to clean your bibliography file and, on the other hand, check the DOI fields. Make sure there aren't duplicates with the fields reserved for URLs.
N.B. extra petita: Check the maxnames and minnames options for the biblatex package: if there is a long list of authors, how many of them would you like to write, before cut the list and write the "and others" string instead?
